# Add description under title of a list view webpart?

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to add a description under title of a list view webpart?

If yes how?

In the image example I need description between "Title" and "DL"

[image]

Comment: Can you give additional details, a screenshot perhaps of where exactly you want the description ?

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: Even I am looking for the solution. Please help.

Comment: One way to approach this would be to use CSS before content property.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very interesting, so in curiosity I created an instance of a view of Custom List using PowerShell. And went through all the publicly available properties and methods. Unfortunately I could not find or relate anything which can be used as a description to the view.

Also I added the list view web part on a page. Edit web part properties and under **Advanced** menu there is a **Description** text box, unfortunately it has no effect.

In this case I think the last resort is the JS Link to give it a try. (*I have never tried adding description, and long time since I last used CSR*)

**Update**:

Or if you are able to add Content Editor Web Part, then write some JavaScrit or jQuery to find the element and embed description below it.